# Video keeps playing after moving to a new route

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-6

I have 2 views A and B, that are loaded in the routes "routeA" and "routeB".

In the view A I'm loading a video.

When I click on the button that exists in the view A that executes `$router.push({ name: 'routeB'})`, it loads the view B, but I can still listen to the video audio, meaning the DOM did not clean whatever was loading on the previous view.

The way I load the routes is like below:

```
const routeA = () => import('./components/A.vue');
const routeB = () => import('./components/B.vue');

export default [
{
    path: '/routeA',
    name: 'routeA',
    component: routeA,
},
{
    path: '/routeB',
    name: 'routeB',
    component: routeB,
},
];
```

Code I use to load the video:

```
let url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var vid = document.getElementById("my_video_player");
vm.video.profile_video_src = url.createObjectURL(xhr.response)+'#t=1';
vid.load();
```

Is it related to the memory leak that is explained here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html?

Is there any chance that I can clean the DOM after moving to another view? Or at least ensure that things like videos don't keep loading / playing?

Comment: How are you playing the video ?

Comment: @ljcordero code added to the OP

Comment: Well what I can recommend is to delete the element on destroy hook.